# Signout the existing login if user signedin again in different device in Identity Server 4

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

If the user is logged in already and trying to login again in a different device or browser then need to logout the existing one

I am using Identity Server 4 in my application.

Which mechanism or steps we can use to achieve this one?

My startup code:

---

```
services.AddIdentity<UserIdentity, UserIdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                // Basic built in validations
                
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdServerDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I was thinking about a similar feature for a website I was developing, that also used Identity Server. If I recall correctly then there isn't anything for this built into Identity Server. But, that doesn't mean you can't code it.

One way would be to keep a integer based log-in counter for the user and increment that each time the user signs in.

Let's say, Bob, signs in on his phone. This is the first time he signs in, ever. Bob's record in the database, has a column that is called `SignInCounter` and it's now set to '1'.

Now if Bob signs in on his PC, let's say an hour later, we set the SignInCounter to '2'.

Now all you need to do is check whether the claim value for `SignInCounter` matches the value that's in the database. It can easily be done on a per-request basis, by using middleware. If it doesn't match, show an error page, sign-out the user, what ever fits your case.

**I really wouldn't recommend this though.** It doesn't scale and also generates +1 database call per request, but hopefully this gives you a general idea how to solve the problem.